# How to run dotnet restore forcing the restore to come from .NETStandard instead of .NETFramework?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-standard-2.1, dotnet-restore, .net-4.8

I had a project which was created in `.NETFramework`. I have followed the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ to convert the solution to `.NETStandard`. In particular all projects in the solution have `.NETStandard` as the Target Framework There are several packages that are restored using `.NETFramework` when I clean and build the projects I get errors/warnings like the following:

`Warning    NU1701  Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`

Is there a way in the Package Manager console to run `dotnet restore` forcing the restore to come from `.NETStandard`?

Answer (score 1):

**[Entity Framework 6.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.1.3) does not support .NET Standard at all**, it only supports the .NET Framework; this is because EF 6.1.3 was released in 2015 before .NET Standard was even a thing.

You need to use [Entity Framework 6.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.3.0) or later for compatibility with .NET Standard.

You should use the latest version: [Entity Framework 6.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.4).

Comment: I have updated to Entity Framework 6.4.4 and get the same error/warning message. The same is happening for other packages, so the error may not be unique to just Entity Framework.

Comment: @ENV Does the same message appear but still referencing `6.1.3` - or does it say `6.4.4.` now? Also, have you tried nuking your solution's `packages` folder?

Comment: Correct. Now it's the same message but for 6.4.4. What do you mean by nuking the solution's packages folder?

Comment: By "nuking the solution's packages", I mean you should delete (or rename) your `packages` directory which is in the same directory as the `*.sln` file (not the same thing as your `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.nuget\packages` directory, leave that one alone).